# Linear CSS Gradient (on Body Tag) IE 11 not working

Tags: css, gradient, internet-explorer-11, linear-gradients

I never expected this issue with IE 11.
If you look at this website asbestoseal.franksdesigns.com you'll see a gradient background with an second background image of Droplets of water.
BUT in IE 11 the gradient doesn't show up
I tried the CSS on this website here: http://jsfiddle.net/SRUGf/1/ 
I was able to get the gradient to show ONLY if I give the body  a height in pixels but of course I want the height to be 100%, not pixels.

CSS

```
body.custom {
    background:#B9D7F0;
    background: url(http://asbestoseal.franksdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/Droplets-small.png) left top repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,56,130,1) 0%, rgba(0,56,130,1) 6%, rgba(70,158,216,1) 65%, rgba(70,158,216,0) 100%);
    background: url(http://asbestoseal.franksdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/Droplets-small.png) left top repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,56,130,1)), color-stop(6%,rgba(0,56,130,1)), color-stop(65%,rgba(70,158,216,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(70,158,216,0)));
    background: url(http://asbestoseal.franksdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/Droplets-small.png) left top repeat, -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,56,130,1) 0%,rgba(0,56,130,1) 6%,rgba(70,158,216,1) 65%,rgba(70,158,216,0) 100%);
    background: url(http://asbestoseal.franksdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/Droplets-small.png) left top repeat,-ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,56,130,1) 0%,rgba(0,56,130,1) 6%,rgba(70,158,216,1) 65%,rgba(70,158,216,0) 100%);
    background: url(http://asbestoseal.franksdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/Droplets-small.png) left top repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,56,130,1) 0%,rgba(0,56,130,1) 6%,rgba(70,158,216,1) 65%,rgba(70,158,216,0) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#003882', endColorstr='#00469ed8',GradientType=0 );
}
```

Comment: Try adding this above your current CSS          html, body { height: 100%;min-height: 100%; }

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS IE body background gradient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012651/css-ie-body-background-gradient)

Comment: This is not really a duplicate if you look at the result of their JS Fiddle and enter this code the behavior is totally different. It is similar but definitely different.

Comment: I might have to give up since I've gotten no resolution. I'm not sure there is a solution to this - I've spent a lot of time working on solutions.

Comment: I gave up on this so the website in question is not relevant now. The question still stands as I'd prefer to use CSS more.